# Problem in creating custom workflow action in SharePoint

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sharepoint-2010, action, sharepoint-workflow

I am trying to create a custom Workflow Action for SharePoint Designer 2010. I am using Visual studio 2010 and followed the steps as mentioned in this link: http://perrystechblog.blogspot.com/2010/08/create-custom-workflow-action-in.html

But still I am not getting the created custom action in the Action list. Any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got it. I saved the xml file as .action in stead of .actions.

Answer (score 1):

I had a very similar issue when following the walkthrough at http://rtmgroupq8.com/en/create-custom-workflow-action-using-visual-studio

In my case when adding the XML file in the Workflow mapped folder I made the mistake of saving the file with its default .xml extension.

Saving the file with a .actions extension and redeploying the solution fixed the problem for me.